# How to deal with out-of-sequence Ajax requests?

Tags: ajax, http, jquery, asynchronous

What is the best way deal with out-of-sequence Ajax requests (preferably using a jQuery)?

For example, an Ajax request is sent from the user's browser anytime a field changes.  A user may change `dog_name` to "Fluffy", but a moment later, she changes it to "Spot".  The first request is delayed for whatever reason, so it arrives at the server after the second, and her dog ends up being called "Fluffy" instead of "Spot".

I could pass along a client-side timestamp along with each request, and have the server track it as part of each `Dog` record and disregard earlier requests to change the same field (but only if there is a difference of less than 5 minutes, in case the user changes the time on her machine).

Is this approach sufficiently robust, or is there a better, more standardized approach?

**EDIT:**

Matt made a great point in his comment.  It's much better to serialize requests to change the same field, so is there a standard way of implementing Ajax request queues?

**EDIT #2**

In response to @cherouvim's comment, I don't think I'd have to lock the form.  The field changes to reflect the user's change, a change request is placed into the queue.  If a request to change the same field is waiting in the queue, delete that old request.  2 things I still would have to address:

1. Placing a request into the queue is an asynchronous task.  I could have the callback handler from the previous Ajax request send the next request in the queue.  Javascript code isn't multi-threaded (or... is it?)
2. If a request fails, I would need the user interface to reflect the state of the last successful request.  So, if the user changes the dog's name to "Spot" and the Ajax request fails, the field would have to be set back to "Fluffy" (the last value successfully committed).

What issues am I missing?

Comment: Simpler: don't allow multiple simultaneous requests for the same field. Queue them if the changes are occurring that rapidly.

Comment: @Matt Ball: and how do you "lock" the whole display-form-push-changes conversation of the client? It's not a single request/response cycle, but two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to serialize server side processing for each client. If you are programming in Java then synchronizing execution on the http session object is sufficient. Serializing will help in case the second update comes while the first is being processed.

A second enhancement you can implement in your entity updating is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control. You add a `version` property (and column) for your entity. Each time an update happens this is incremented once. In fact the update statement looks like:

```
update ... set version=6 ... where id=? and version=5;
```

If affected rows from above pseudoquery query are 0 then someone else has managed to update the entity first. What you do then is up to you. Note that you need to be rendering the version on the html update form of the entity as a hidden parameter and sending it back to the server each time you update. On return you have to write back the updated version.

Generally the first enhancement would be enough. The second one will improve the system in case many people are editing the same entities at the same time. It solves the "lost update" problem.

Comment: The version control is a good point, but in this case I am not worried about users clobbering each others' updates with stale data. In my case, a series of small updates originate from the same user in quick succession.

Comment: The versioning applies on each and every update, even from the same user. Each ajax field update is a version increment. So your "spot" change will increment the version from 5 to 6 and your, stale, "fluffy" will be detected as a stale update (because it'll send a version 5 as well) and you can do whatever you want, e.g ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement a queue on the client side with chaining of successful requests or rollbacks on unsuccessful requests.

You need to define "unsuccessful", be it a timeout or a returned value.